# Firebase chat, online users and page refresh takes user offline and back to online

Tags: firebase

I have implemented Firebase chat but the only issue is that when a user is online and refreshes the page or clicks on a link to go to another page, they go offline for a seconds and they're back online.

Is there a ways to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase is just another resource that your web page loads, similar to all the HTML, JavaScript and images that it needs to load. If the user refreshes the page, all those resources need to be reloaded too (either from the server or from cache).

There is no way to prevent this for any resources, so also not for the Firebase connection. Maybe you could use a service worker to keep the connection alive, but that's beyond a simple answer.